# How do I select first and last child of same class in parent element?

Tags: html, css

I want to select first and last element with class "x" in each div.

When I use the CSS code below, only last element in first container and first element in last container are selected. How do I select first and last elements of same class in parent elements?

```css
div>.x:first-child {
  background: green;
}

div>.x:last-child {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    123
  </p>
  <p class="x">
    123
  </p>
  <p class="x">
    123
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="x">
    123
  </p>
  <p class="x">
    123
  </p>
  <p>
    123
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming that unlike in the HTML you posted that you'll have paragraphs with the x class that aren't the first or last?

Comment: you can find a workaround for the *first* but I don't think so for *last*

Comment: `:first-child` selects elements that matches the selector and is also the first child in its parent. Likewise for `:last-child`.